# How to add a new element to the top of a table-jscript-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and I am supposed to add a new element to the top of a table, right now the new element is getting added according to the preexisting order. Can anyone at least tell me what this function is doing?

```
 $.fn.addCellInfoActionItem = function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
rows.push(nRow);
var isEditable =  aData[0];
var isStatusEditable =  aData[1];
var moduleId =  aData[3];
var dueDateOverDue = aData[4];
var aimManaged =  aData[5];
var isLastResponseEditable =  aData[6];
var readOnlyToolTipText = aData[8];
var actionItemId =  aData[10];
var actionItemstatus =  aData[14];
var parenttr = $(nRow).closest('tr')[0];
var rowCellObjs = datatable.fnGetTds(parenttr);
var settingSize = datatable.dataTableSettings.length;
var headerCols;
```

Comment: Adds to `rows` array new entry and creates bunch of unused elements

Comment: Please mark as accepted/vote if one of the answers was helpful or give us feedback if problem still exists.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a function like table.push(e), but putting e at 0 index ?

try this :

```
table=[e].concat(table)
```

Comment: thanks, but i am new to programming so sorry for asking but exactly where i have to add this function?

Answer (score 0):

That function is not complete.. what is it doing in the missing code? But it seems it's a "preparing work" for what is there. Variable initializations and a adding of a element to a array.

You can use jquery's prepend() and append() to do dom-manipulations and to add e.g. like in your case a row (dom-element) wherever you exactly want..

See here:
http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

There it says:

> The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child
>   of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last
>   child, use .append()